# update UITableViewCell height in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm trying to have a `UITableViewCell` that when scrolls away, collapses to a preview.

I managed to do it, with boolean values - that is - in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I change a boolean array of all the cells before the current cell.

In iOS8 it works perfectly - the problem is that in iOS7 `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called only on tableView Load.

I know I can make:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

But I can't do it inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (it crashes)

Where can I run it?

The code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[collapsedChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == YES)
    {
        return 73;
    }
    //else - calculate
    return 200; //the number is actually calculated - but simplifying
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell =[self generateChapterCell:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
        [self handleLastVisible];
        return cell;
}

- (void)handleLastVisible
{

    NSInteger lastVisibleChapter = [self getLastVisibleRowOfSection:self.tableView section:chaptersSectionNum];
    if (lastVisibleChapter > lastViewedChapter) //should work for -1 and 9999 as well
    {
        lastViewedChapter = lastVisibleChapter;
    }

    NSInteger firstVisibleChapter = [self getFirstVisibleRowOfSection:self.tableView section:chaptersSectionNum];
    if (firstVisibleChapter == -1)
    {
        //we are before - don't touch
        return;
    }

    NSNumber* yesObj = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    //in case of 9999 - we will stop at the end of the for loop - it's OK
    for (int i=0; i < [collapsedChapters count]; i++)
    {
        if (i == firstVisibleChapter)
        {
            break;
        }
        if ([[collapsedChapters objectAtIndex:i] boolValue] == NO)
        {
            [chapterFirstCollapse replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:yesObj];
        }
        [collapsedChapters replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:yesObj];
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually `heightForRowAtIndexPath` should be called every time a cell is going to be displayed. If it's not working on iOS7 you must have done something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I notice that `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` calls `[[collapsedChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == YES`. I'm assuming that means the value of the boolean is a toggle that says whether or not a particular cell is 'expanded', right?

If so, I had exactly the same problem several years ago. Rather than having a single section for the whole table and then one row per 'chapter', have one *section* per 'chapter' and then change the number of rows per section based on whether the 'chapter' is expanded or collapsed - 1 row for collapsed, 2 rows for expanded. For expanded 'chapters' you put the expanded info in the 2nd row in the section.

This way to expand a chapter you can use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` and to collapse, `removeRowsAtIndexPaths:` and everything will just work, including all the nice table view animations that users expect.

Comment: Yeah... but in my case the cells are different (it is not just added information) so this trick won't work...

Comment: Ok - this was some years ago but I do remember feeling like the API was really fighting against me when trying to do this. Are you sure you can't redesign it so the extra information just pops out the bottom?